# Redirect url like www.url.com/test/client2 to something like www.mydomain.com/test.php?clientid=2

Tags: redirection

Firstly I'm not sure whether I'm asking at the right place or not (either here or stackoverflow). Sorry, if I'm not.

Before that:

My site runs on apache and developed using PHP.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. My client can generate a registration page for its customers.
2. The default generated registration page URL is something like `www.mydomain.com/test.php?clientid=2`
3. But the url is long and ugly, so I created another option for the client to generate a prettier looking url, which starts with a shorter domain (eg: like.my) and a customizable 'path' after that. So the resulting pretty url my client want is like `http://like.my/page`.
4. So there is a simple way to redirect the traffic from `http://like.my/page` to `http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?clientid=2`?
5. Btw I have thousands of clients and each of them would have different pretty url pointing to different other pages.

Comment: hmmm @dawud thanks for your comment but is there any way of doing it programatically?

Comment: It depends on your application server software. If it is made with a framework, chances are that the framework contains a routing component, which handles these things easily. Then you only insert the rewrite rule shown in framework's documentation to `.htaccess`, and you have pretty URLs in use then.

Comment: thanks @TeroKilkanen for the explanation. my application wasn't written using any framework. so is there anyway I can refer to so I can write the same type of routing component that these frameworks have?

Comment: This is Symfony2's router component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html .